# Congruence transformation of symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices, matrix-congruences

Given a symmetric matrix $A$ of size $n$ and an arbitrary invertible square matrix $P$ (also of size $n$), what can we say about the congruence transformation: $$P^TAP?$$

- Does this matrix necessarily have to be a symmetric matrix?
- When is the corresponding matrix symmetric (and not symmetric)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 
$$
(P^TAP)^T=P^TA^TP^{TT}=P^TAP. 
$$